# Get all text within parent node with xpath

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I just started using Xpath for a project in PHP. I have to get the individual prices for each product from a website. Each individual product's price info has the following format:

```
<div class="priceStockDetail">
    <dl>
        <dt>Across any 6</dt>
        <dd><span class='price '><span class='currency'>$</span>20<span class=cents>.90</span></span></dd>

        <dt>Each</dt>
        <dd><span class='price '><span class='currency'>$</span>22<span class=cents>.00</span></span></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I wish to get only the text after `<dt>Each</dt>` as one ("$22.00" for the example above) with an Xpath expression.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either target each piece element and concatenate, or just target the parent and get the nodeValue. Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
$products = $xpath->query('//dt');
if($products->length > 0) {
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $product_name = $product->nodeValue;

        // either get individually

        // $currency = $xpath->evaluate('string(./following-sibling::dd[1]/span/span[@class="currency"])', $product);
        // $price = $xpath->evaluate('string(./following-sibling::dd[1]/span/span[@class="currency"]/following-sibling::text())', $product);
        // $cents = $xpath->evaluate('string(./following-sibling::dd[1]/span/span[@class="cents"])', $product);
        // $product_price = $currency.$price.$cents;

        // or
        $product_price = $xpath->evaluate('string(./following-sibling::dd[1]/span)', $product);


        $data[] = array(
            'product_name' => $product_name,
            'product_price' => $product_price,
        );
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hB9gkK)

Comment: Why don't you use `$product_price = $xpath->evaluate('string(./following-sibling::dd[1]/span)', $product);`?

Comment: @ThW yeah could just evaluate it overlooked it :)